# Why does method change the boolean array parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, boolean, path-finding

I have a class for finding a path through a basic maze. A maze is passed to path along with starting and ending positions. I use recursion to find a path between the points. The path is returned as a boolean array. For some reason the initial maze passed to the Path() gets changed. So I tried making a copy of the maze array to avoid changing any values but it is still not working.

Why is path() making changes to open[][]? Might be the C programming confusing me here.

```
public static boolean[][] path(boolean[][] open, 
                               int start_i, int start_j, 
                               int end_i, int end_j) 
{
    int n = open.length;
    boolean[][] openCopy = new boolean[n][n]; //make a copy of open

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            openCopy[i][j] = open[i][j]; 
        }
    } 
    return findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j, end_i, end_j);
}

public static boolean[][] findPath(boolean[][] openCopy, int start_i, int start_j, int end_i, int end_j) 
{
    boolean[][] path = new boolean[openCopy.length][openCopy[0].length];

    if(openCopy[start_i][start_j] == false) //return false if current position is not open
        return path;
    else
        openCopy[start_i][start_j] = false;  //make current position false if not (to prevent infinite backtracking)

    if(start_i == end_i && start_j == end_j) //if end found return true
    {
        path[start_i][start_j] = true;
        return path;
    }

    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i+1, start_j, end_i, end_j); // Move North
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j+1, end_i, end_j); // Move East
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i-1, start_j, end_i, end_j); // Move South
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j-1, end_i, end_j); // Move West

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Look at this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127530/does-array-changes-in-method

Comment: @AKS "boolean[][] openCopy = new boolean[n][n];" should create a new array which can be changed without changing the original array. At least I think so.

Comment: How are you seeing the value change? Nothing here would affect the array `open` passed into `path()`

Comment: @DHall I printed 'open' before passing to path() and then printed it afterwards and it doesn't match. I will check my printing again for mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesnt, I know this might not be exactly 'appropriate' input for the method, but it proves the point:

```
public class MainForm {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] array = new boolean[][] {{false, false, true, false, false, false}, 
            {false, false, true, false, false, false}, 
            {false, false, true, false, false, false}, 
            {false, false, true, false, false, false}};

    boolean[] [] another = path(array, 0, 0, 3, 5);

    for (boolean[] bArray : array) {
        for (boolean b : bArray) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("***********************");
    for (boolean[] bArray : another) {
        for (boolean b : bArray) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean[][] path(boolean[][] open, int start_i, int start_j, int end_i, int end_j) {
    int n = open.length;
    boolean[][] openCopy = new boolean[n][n]; // make a copy of open

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            openCopy[i][j] = open[i][j];
        }
    }
    return findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j, end_i, end_j);
}

public static boolean[][] findPath(boolean[][] openCopy, int start_i, int start_j, int end_i, int end_j) {
    boolean[][] path = new boolean[openCopy.length][openCopy[0].length];

    if (openCopy[start_i][start_j] == false) // return false if current position is not open
        return path;
    else
        openCopy[start_i][start_j] = false; // make current position false if not (to prevent infinite backtracking)

    if (start_i == end_i && start_j == end_j) // if end found return true
    {
        path[start_i][start_j] = true;
        return path;
    }

    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i + 1, start_j, end_i, end_j); // Move North
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j + 1, end_i, end_j); // Move East
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i - 1, start_j, end_i, end_j); // Move South
    path = findPath(openCopy, start_i, start_j - 1, end_i, end_j); // Move West

    return path;
}
}
```

output

```
false
false
true
false
false
false
false
false
true
false
false
false
false
false
true
false
false
false
false
false
true
false
false
false
***********************
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Clearly the returned array and the one passed into path() are different in their contents, and the original values of the original array remain intact. I think the problem lies elsewhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is, that you are passing around references in your inner *for*-loop.
Try instead of this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            openCopy[i][j] = open[i][j]; 
        }
```

this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    openCopy[i][j] = new Boolean(open[i][j]);
}
```

I think it should help.

Comment: since the array is declared `boolean[][]` not `Boolean[][]`, they should be primitives and therefore not references. Does java automatically box/unbox primitives in an array of primitives?

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. Boxing unboxing is completely automatic in java. no need to worry about that, as i experienced.

Comment: Well program just crashed and now path isn't working at all :/

Comment: What does stacktrace say? java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?